# Cisco vpn connection issues. Perhaps router related?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, sftp, cisco-vpn-client

First, sorry if this is the wrong community for asking this. Or if this is a duplicate.

I have a cisco vpn connection to a remote server. I can connect to this computer via ssh with no problems. I can also do `cd` and `ls`, with no problems. However, as soon as I do something like reading a file with `vim`, or opening a graphics file, or viewing the files on the local machine from the server using `sftp`, the connection crashes.

I tried to bypass this issue using `scp` to copy the files from the server to the local machine. With no luck, because the download becomes stalled immediately. I also tried using `rsync`, with no luck either.

All of this, when using the same local computer at my home. But the interesting part is that I just went to another people house. There, using the local computer, I could connect via ssh to the remote server, but I also could use `vim` to read the files from there with no problem, and I could also use `sftp` with no observable issue at all. Which is why I wonder if this might be related to the router or the isp.

So, the question is, what do you suggest me to do, so as to be able to fix this?

PS: my local computer has ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you can temporarily bypass the router you think is at fault, start there.

Comment: @ITSnuggles. To your first question, yes, indeed, that is the case. To your second question: to be clear, the local computer from which i speak, is a notebook. Which i used both at home (with problems), and at the other place (with no problems). In both cases, I had the exact same os on the local computer. Now, as for 'terminal clients', what does that mean? sorry to ask this. Tried a brief google search, didn't find any result.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try this, though it'll take me a while before I can actually do this.

Comment: Cool, because you were using the same machine then it doesn't matter. I wasn't sure if at your house you used Ubuntu terminal and perhaps at the other location you used a Windows machine with Putty for example to connect via SSH. You've clarified what I asked so that's good enough for what I was asking as I didn't get from the post you used two different Internet from the same one mobile machine so you're all good sir!!

Comment: @ITSnuggles. Yes, looking back, my wording of the issue was not very precise. Apologies for being confusing.